# How to clone an instance of the QML type "vector2d"?

Tags: qt, qml, clone

I could do:

```
var b = Qt.vector2d(a.x, a.y)
```

But that's not elegant, especially when `a` has a long name.

What other ways are there?

Answer (score 3):

If your concern are mainly the long names, write a function:

```
function cloneVector(a) { return Qt.vector2d(a.x, a.y) }
```

Now you need to write long name only once

```
cloneVector(vectorWithAnAmazinglyLongNameAndSoOn)
```